# Javascript sort array by key descending Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-chrome, sorting

I have an array and need to sort it in descending order by the key.
All working good in Firefox but in Chrome it's showing in the original order

```
[["0", 0], ["1", 0.9], ["2", 597.5344192965547], ["3", 991.0326954186761], ["4", 1257.2580315846578], ["5", 1293.5250901880618], ["6", 2197.1091224116512], ["7", 2225.0422585266947], ["8", 3964.1307816747044], ["9", 6914.072436146399]]
```

This is the code I am using

```
sortable.sort(function(a,b){return b-a})
```

So in Firefox it returns the correct result

```
[["9", 6914.072436146399], ["8", 3964.1307816747044], ["7", 2225.0422585266947], ["6", 2197.1091224116512], ["5", 1293.5250901880618], ["4", 1257.2580315846578], ["3", 991.0326954186761], ["2", 597.5344192965547], ["1", 0.9], ["0", 0]]
```

But in google Chrome it just displays the same

Comment: You have an array of arrays. What do you expect (for instance) `["0", 0] - ["1", 0.9]` to mean? That's what your `b - a` comes down to (at some point), assuming that `sortable` refers to your outer array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have an array of arrays. Assuming `sortable` refers to the outer array, your sorting function ends up using `-` on *array instances*. For instance, at some point when you call `sort`, your sorting function is called with the arrays `["0", 0]` and `["1", 0.9]`. So you effectively do this in that function:

```
return ["0", 0] - ["1", 0.9];
```

Using `-` on those two operands will result in the JavaScript engine trying to turn those operands into numbers, almost certainly resulting in `NaN`. `NaN - NaN` is `NaN`, which isn't one of the things the sorting comparator callback is supposed to return.

I suspect you want to sort by the first entry in the subordinate arrays, like this:

```
sortable.sort(function(a,b){return b[0]-a[0]})
```

(Note the `[0]` on each.) That will get the strings that are the first entries in each subordinate array and pass them to `-`, which will implicitly coerce them to numbers. You could also make that explicit and force a specific radix if desired:

```
sortable.sort(function(a,b){return parseInt(b[0], 10) - parseInt(a[0], 10)})
```

Comment: Aren't you missing `parseInt` or something? ;)

Comment: @thefourtheye: It may or may not be needed. `-` will coerce the args to numbers. But I'll add it.

Comment: Oh yeah, you are right. `ToPrimitive` will take care of that. +1